# Lookup admin change url for arbitrary Django model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How do you lookup the admin change url for an arbitrary model?

If I know the model, I can get the url by doing something like:

```
>>> print urlresolvers.reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change', args=(obj.id,))
/admin/myapp/mymodel/123/
```

I have a generic foreign key on a model, and I'd like to provide a link in admin to the object's corresponding change page. Since it can be any type of model, I can't easily use reverse(). Is there some way I could simply this to the following?

```
>>> get_admin_change_url(obj)
/admin/myapp/mymodel/123/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the object, you can access its app label and name on its `_meta` class, then construct the name of the admin change url dynamically.

```
app_label = obj._meta.app_label
model = obj._meta.module_name

reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (app_label, model), args=(obj.id,))
```

Comment: Note, this assumes your admin.py matches your models.py, which is usually will. This won't work if you're using proxy model, or show a model's modeladmin under a different app_label.

Comment: It will work fine if you use your proxy model as *the* model for the `ModelAdmin`. I'm not sure why you *wouldn't* do that, since you wouldn't really be working with the right thing at that point.

Comment: You would. I have a use case where I present different admin views depending on the context/user. One is based on the original model, the other on proxies for that model.

Comment: Actually, `reverse()` does work for proxy models. If your proxy happens to live on a different site, you have to use that site prefix, e.g. `reverse('mysite:myapp_myproxy_changelist')`, where `mysite` is different from `admin`.